# Unable to invoke openwhisk functions locally

Tags: node.js, serverless, openwhisk

I am unable to invoke a sequence using serverless openwhisk (0.18.3). I followed the example at https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/openwhisk-node-chaining-functions but after executing the command `serverless invoke --function chained_seq --data '{"message": "a b c d e"}'` I recieved the following error:

"Serverless command "invoke local a b c d e}'" not found. Did you mean "invoke"? Run "serverless help" for a list of all available commands."

I then customized the function to work without parameters but got the error:

"Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: The  `'{"message": "a b c d e"}'` format needs changing for the Windows CLI. You need to escape the " characters in the string.

Comment: But what about the invoking a function without parameter? It still gives the error "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"